# Not able to display properly the hyperlinks because style=display:none

Tags: jquery

In the below

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btnSearchCancel').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();            
                $('ul#tabs li').toggleClass('active');
                $("ul#tabs li").not(".active").hide();              
            });
            $('#btnSearch').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();            
                $('ul#tabs li').toggleClass('active');
                $("ul#tabs li").not(".active").hide();              
            });
        });
</script>
<body>

<div id="divMenuTab">
    <ul id="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="aTabDocuments" > <span></span>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="aTabSearch"><span></span>Search</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>

<div id="divSearchTab">
<input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnSearchCancel" name="btnSearchCancel" class="btnPrimary" style="width: 60px;"/>
<input type="submit" class="btnPrimary" value="Search" id="btnSearch" name="btnSearch"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

when the Cancel button is clicked, I want to show only the "Search hyperlink" and when the "Search" button is clicked, I want to show only the Home hyper link. But cannot do that because "style=display:none". How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Put your code in fiddle or live demo ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `show()` function as well.You are just hiding the elements which are `not(".active")` in both the cases. You also need to show the `active` ones otherwise the display attribute will still be none, from the previous use of `hide()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btnSearchCancel').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();            
                $('ul#tabs li').toggleClass('active');
                $("ul#tabs li").not(".active").hide(); 
              $("ul#tabs li.active").show(); 
            });
            $('#btnSearch').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();            
                $('ul#tabs li').toggleClass('active');
                $("ul#tabs li").not(".active").hide();
              $("ul#tabs li.active").show(); 
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="divMenuTab">
    <ul id="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="aTabDocuments" > <span></span>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="aTabSearch"><span></span>Search</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>

<div id="divSearchTab">
<input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnSearchCancel" name="btnSearchCancel" class="btnPrimary" style="width: 60px;"/>
<input type="submit" class="btnPrimary" value="Search" id="btnSearch" name="btnSearch"/>
</div>
```